# Environment check in OnModelCreating

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, seeding

I am seeding my data in OnModelCreating method in ApplicationDbContext.cs. I would like to always add some data, but also to add some data conditionally (only if the environment is development).

How can I achieve that? I cannot change method signature to have "IHostingEnvironment env" because in that case it won't be overriding OnModelCreating.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add property in appsettings.json and add your logic based on this property

Answer (score 5):

`DbContext` has an internal service provider that you can utilize:

```
var env = this.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    // seed
}
```

You'll need to modify `services.AddDbContext` a little:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o => o
    .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"))
    .UseInternalServiceProvider());
```