# How to get environment variable in OnModelCreating()?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm calling a method in OnModelCreating() in DbContext.
I do not want it to be called in every environment.

Saw this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51863802/environment-check-in-onmodelcreating).

Tried to implement it like this.
OnModelCreating() in DbContext implementation.

```
  var env = this.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
  if (env.EnvironmentName == "Development")
  {
      modelBuilder.SeedData();
  }
```

In Program.cs

```
 services
            .AddDbContext<TDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionStringName))
            .UseInternalServiceProvider()
            .AddInterceptors(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SOMESERVICE>()));
```

UseInternalServiceProvider() is not recognized and I get compile-time error.
I'm using .net 6 and maybe, question I linked used an old version.

UPDATE : Tried

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")
```

But it returns null

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @stuartd it says there is no argument for serviceProvider. When I put null to it and add ef migration, I get error saying, "unable to resolve Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment"

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927300/cant-find-iwebhostenvironment-in-microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-abstractions-asse

Comment: I added that itemgroup but didn't help for some reason

Comment: Have you tried simply adding a `IWebHostEnvironment` parameter to the DbContext contructor that has the `DbContextOptions` parameter? It should get injected for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

In net core 6 I used like this, the app is the app=builder.build(); in Program.cs

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{

}